# How to get values from Class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, listview, loops

I am building a C# WPF app. My app contains ListView with multiple Column. I added column and binding in Listview with XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="receiptList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="209.987" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="645" Margin="111,135.748,0,0" IsEnabled="False"  >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ReceiptID" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReceiptID}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ItemNo" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemNo}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ItemName" Width="240" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="PackingSize" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PackingSize}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity"  Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price"  Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ExpiryDate"  Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ExpiryDate}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now with help of button i add rows in Listview:

```
private void addItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{             
    AddItems addItems = new AddItems(hhk,2,"ABC","36X63",3,opop,"22-11-2014");
    receiptList.Items.Add(addItems);
}
```

AddItems Class:

```
class AddItems
{
    public int ReceiptID { get; set; }
    public int ItemNo { get; set; }

    public String ItemName { get; set; }
    public String PackingSize { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public String ExpiryDate { get; set; }

    public AddItems()
    {

    }

    public AddItems(int oid, int itNo, string itName, string itSize, int qua, float pri, String eDate)
    {
        this.ReceiptID = oid;
        this.ItemNo = itNo;
        this.ItemName = itName;
        this.PackingSize = itSize;
        this.Quantity = qua;
        this.Price = pri;
        this.ExpiryDate = eDate;
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a method which counts how many items are added in AddItems and also I want to retrieve items from AddItems with the help of a loop.

Comment: As a first comment ordeID.text does not compile should be orderID.Text

Comment: writing some sql would probably be a good start...

Comment: As a second comment look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Not directly relevant to this question, but if you'd like your app to be used by multiple users, then you may need a better solution (than this current number+1 for ID).

Comment: This is a **horribly bad** approach, since in a system with any kind of usage and traffic, you **will have DUPLICATES** in no time at all! This is **NOT** safe in a concurrent, busy system! You should use some database-internal mechanism (e.g. `INT IDENTITY` column in SQL Server) to **safely** handle this....

Answer (score 2):

This is *NOT* a good idea. I'll explain why:

1. User A starts your program and gets a new order ID based on the current maximum order ID in the database
2. User B starts your program and gets exactly the same order ID as nothing has been updated so far.
3. Both user A and B save the orders - and you get two different orders with the same ID.

Please, do yourself and your users a favour an do it correctly from the start: Either have the database assign the order ID upon insert *or* create a number-series table that updates to a new order ID whenever an order ID is queried.

EXAMPLE:

Table NumberSeries could contain the following fields:

```
SeriesName        MinID           MaxID         CurrentValue
Orders            1               999999        817
```

The following stored procedure would get the next possible order ID *safely*!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetNextNo
    @seriesName
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @newNo TABLE (Value INT)

    UPDATE NumberSeries
    SET
        CurrentValue = CurrentValue + 1
    OUTPUT INSERTED.CurrentValue INTO @newNo
    WHERE 
        SeriesName = @seriesName AND
        CurrentValue < MaxID

    SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM @newNo
END
```

You can then use this from C# as follows:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetNextNo", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seriesName", "Orders");

    object res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (res == null || res == DBNull.Value)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Number series is used up");

    return (int)res;
}
```

---

EDIT I checked out HABO's approach from the comments and the following works, too:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetNextNo
    @seriesName
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @newNo INT

    UPDATE NumberSeries
    SET
        @newNo = CurrentValue += 1
    WHERE 
        SeriesName = @seriesName AND
        CurrentValue < MaxID

    SELECT @newNo
END
```

---

EDIT You asked in the comments whether this is possible without using stored procedures. I actually have not tried this from C#, but I've entered the following using a test table in SQL Management Studio and it worked.

```
exec('declare @var int; update tTest set @var = test += 1; select @var;')
```

This yields the correct results in my case. You could now try to execute the above statement using an `SqlCommand` like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec('declare @var int; update tTest set @var = test += 1; select @var;')", conn)
{
    object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    ...
}
```

Of course you could also use the number series table I suggested above and adjust the query as needed.

That could be also worth trying. OTOH, why don't you want to use stored procedures?

Comment: SQL Server allows a strange syntax within an `UPDATE`: `SET @AssignedId = CurrentValue += 1`. This will increment the stored value and return the updated value in an `INT` variable `@AssignedId`. It avoids creating a temporary table for trivial cases.

Comment: @HABO Didn't know that! Going to try this ASAP. A sigh of relief was heard in our office when I just informed the collegues about that! Thanks :-)

Comment: If you need before and after values: `set @Before = Thing, @After = Thing += 3000`. Be very afraid!

Comment: is there a way, we can do it without procedures